# Failed to install tensorflow on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, ubuntu-17.10

When trying to install tensorflow on ubuntu 17.10 (python 3.6) i got this error:

```
Collecting tensorflow==1.7.0 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.7.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
could not find a version that satisfies the requirement astor>=0.6.0 (from tensorflow==1.7.0) (from versions: )
no matching distribution found for astor>=0.6.0 (from tensorflow==1.7.0)
```

when trying to install tensorflow 1.6.0 I got this error

```
could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorboard<1.7.0,>=1.6.0 (from tensorflow==1.6.0) (from versions: )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by this command

```
pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org tensorflow
```

In fact the problem is related to the ssl

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
pip3 install grpcio==1.9.1 tensorflow==1.6.0
```

Comment: `no matching distribution found for grpcio==1.9.1`

Comment: thank you for your reply... but i found the same problem